# AppDelegate not responding to NSNotification

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter, appdelegate

I would like to use my app's AppDelegate to post a CRToast notification

Here's how I'm adding the observer.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(noConnectionNotification)
                                                 name:@"No_Connection_Available" object:nil];

}
```

and here's the method it's supposed to call

```
-(void)noConnectionNotification{
     NSLog(@"received notification");
    NSString *notificationString = @"Unable to reach server. Changes will be cached.";
    NSDictionary *options = @{kCRToastTextKey : notificationString,
                              kCRToastNotificationTypeKey : @(CRToastTypeStatusBar),
                              kCRToastTextAlignmentKey : @(NSTextAlignmentCenter),
                              kCRToastBackgroundColorKey : [UIColor redColor],
                              kCRToastAnimationInDirectionKey : @(CRToastAnimationDirectionTop),
                              kCRToastAnimationOutDirectionKey : @(CRToastAnimationDirectionTop),
                              kCRToastTimeIntervalKey : @(2),
                              };
    [CRToastManager showNotificationWithOptions:options
                                completionBlock:nil];
}
```

and how I'm posting the notification from a different class:

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"No_Connection_Available" object:nil];
        });
    }
```

The method doesn't get called. If I make one of my various view controllers an observer, that one gets the notification, but the AppDelegate isn't. Is it just not possible to make the AppDelegate a NSNotification observer?

Answer (score 4):

Your method that gets called when receiving the notification needs to have a `NSNotification` argument. So, the method should look like this:

```
-(void)noConnectionNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {
     NSLog(@"received notification");
    NSString *notificationString = @"Unable to reach server. Changes will be cached.";
    NSDictionary *options = @{kCRToastTextKey : notificationString,
                              kCRToastNotificationTypeKey : @(CRToastTypeStatusBar),
                              kCRToastTextAlignmentKey : @(NSTextAlignmentCenter),
                              kCRToastBackgroundColorKey : [UIColor redColor],
                              kCRToastAnimationInDirectionKey : @(CRToastAnimationDirectionTop),
                              kCRToastAnimationOutDirectionKey : @(CRToastAnimationDirectionTop),
                              kCRToastTimeIntervalKey : @(2),
                              };
    [CRToastManager showNotificationWithOptions:options
                                completionBlock:nil];
}
```

Then, adding the observer should look like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(noConnectionNotification:)
                                                 name:@"No_Connection_Available" object:nil];

}
```

Note the colon after the method name in the `@selector` call.

Comment: I tried it but it still doesn't work. I have a breakpoint set at the `noConnectionNotification` method and it never gets tripped.

Comment: @JosephToronto Is the `noConnectionNotification:` method a member of your AppDelegate class?

Comment: If you mean did I declare it in AppDelegate.h, then yes I did.